# Running time for binary search tree

Tags: algorithm

The textbook says the number of split operations is bounded by the height of the tree,  which is O(logn).

I dont quite understand why it is bounded by the height of the tree? Can someone explain that?

Comment: Please be more specific on what exactly you are referring to.

Answer (score 0):

When you start at the root, and go as far as you can down some path towards the bottom, the maximum number of nodes you can come across is equal to the height of the tree (this should be easy to see and it is, pretty much by definition, the height of the tree).

Now when you're searching in a binary search tree, you start at the root, and, at each step, you look at the current node, and stop, go left or go right (going left or going right can be considered a split operation). This process involves the same number of nodes as the one described above (going from the root down some path), which involves encountering a number of nodes, and thus split operations, no more than the height of the tree.

Also note that the height of the tree is only O(log n) if the tree is balanced (see [this page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-balancing_binary_search_tree) for more).

Answer (score 0):

Most probably, in the textbook you are referring to, the data structure in question in a balanced binary tree with `n` nodes. Since it is balanced, its height is `log(n)`. Detailed definitions and brief explanations converning the height ca be found [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-balancing_binary_search_tree).